# IndexOutOfBoundsException handing in Java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Please find my code

```
public ArrayList<String> addtocartdisabled() {
    ArrayList<String> checkbox_property = new ArrayList<String>();
    WebElement portfoliotable = cpi.tbl_portfolio;
    List<WebElement> allRows = portfoliotable
            .findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    String rowvalue = "";

    for (int row = 1; row < allRows.size(); row++) {
        String Incart = driver
                .findElement(
                        By.xpath("//*[@id='tblPortfolio']/tbody/tr[" + row
                                + "]/td[9]")).getText().trim();

        if (Incart.equals("In Cart")) {
            rowvalue = Integer.toString(row);
            checkbox_property.add(rowvalue);
            break;
        }
    }
    return checkbox_property;
}
```

And another method will receive the returned value for this method `(addtocartdisabled)`

```
public ArrayList<String> patentportfolio_scrapwithoutaddtoCart()
        throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<String> Actual_result = addtocartdisabled();
    String addtocartrecord = Actual_result.get(0);
    }
```

During the Execution `addtocartdiasbled` method does not return any value in this situation, and we receive `"IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0"`

let me know how we can handled this Exception

Comment: Check whether the list contains any elements before trying to get elements!

Comment: allRows what size does it have ?

Comment: Use iterator and iterate through it while it has next element. like `while(iterator.hasNext())`

Comment: Why  for loop starts with index(row = 1;) 1 instead of 0. any reason?

Comment: `for (int row = 1; row < allRows.size()` you should probably start at index `0`

Comment: row variable mapping with tr (<tr> tag) to scrap the first row value of that table, so it could not possible to start with zero (tring Incart = driver
                .findElement(
                        By.xpath("//*[@id='tblPortfolio']/tbody/tr[" + row
                                + "]/td[9]")).getText().trim();

Answer (score 0):

Because, `addtocartdisabled()` method may return empty `List` as you added value here under condition of `if (Incart.equals("In Cart")) {`, which may be always false. To avoid this exception you can empty check on `ArrayList`.

```
public ArrayList<String> patentportfolio_scrapwithoutaddtoCart()
    throws InterruptedException {
  ArrayList<String> Actual_result = addtocartdisabled();

  if(!Actual_result.isEmpty()){
   String addtocartrecord = Actual_result.get(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual_result.get(0) assumes that you have at least one element present.

If your Incart is never satisfied then you will never have anything in

```
String Incart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tblPortfolio']/tbody/tr[" + row + "]/td[9]")).getText().trim();
```

This is why you get the error.